# Overriding virtual with pure virtual..Is it ok?

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

Example:

```
class IGui{
  protected:
  virtual bool OnClicked(){return false;}
  virtual bool OnHover(){return false;}
  virtual bool OnScrollBarChange(){return false;}
  virtual bool OnTextChange(){return false;}

  ...

}

class IGuiButton: public IGui{
  protected:

  virtual bool OnClicked() = 0;
  virtual bool OnHover(){
    do stuff
    return true;}
  ...
}
```

The point is having a commom interface for all gui types that can be (where not all virtuals need to be overridden), and then provide a lite specialization for a button, but for the button, theres must be a override for the OnClicked..

Also, I think I should make the ones a button shouldnt override private( so use private inheritance, and use that fancy "using Base::Method;" for making the specific ones protected?

Comment: You could just try it an find out, or are you asking whether it is a good design?

Comment: @John3136, yep, Im looking for recommendations, Im kinda used to get smashed about my implementation choices ._.

Comment: What is the use case for the common interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple sides to the question. The first one is actually a quite interesting question:

> *Can a derived class have a pure virtual method that is not pure in the base?*

The answer is *yes*, it can. With the expected (if you expected this to work) semantics: a type derived from the intermediate type must implement the virtual function not to be an abstract type. This leads to a curious circumstance, where the base is not abstract, but the derived type is... which will be surprising. Just for this, I would avoid this in a design.

> *Should you mark as `private` the members that deriving types should not override?*

No, there is no reason or advantage to do that. Whether the member function is `public`, `protected` or `private` derived classes can override it. Any code that can call the functions through the base type will still be able to call it by casting to base. This leads to another *strange* thing in your design. The base class is filled with `protected` virtual functions, which means that they are accessible only by the derived type. This does not define an interface and cannot be used as such. If a function/class takes a reference to a `IGui`, or a `IGuiButton` it will not be able to do much, as there is no public interface. That basically means that noone will be able to call any of the events --unless you are also abusing friendship to provide access to the event handler, but you should avoid it.

> *So what is a proper design?*

There are different alternatives. I'd recommend that before creating your own *square wheel* you look at those wheels that were invented in the past: look at different graphical frameworks and libraries and try to understand why they decided to design them as such. Look at the differences and try to determine what advantages/disadvantages they bring and which option matches your problem. UI is a domain where there is a lot of prior art, and chances are you will not design from scratch anything better than people in the field have done in the past --you might do it, but it is much easier to fall in the same pitfalls everyone else felt before.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to say I think what you are trying to do is poor design.

Your top level (IGui) "has everything" and then you are effectively taking stuff out as you move down the class hierarchy. The top level would normally have the common stuff and you add the differences as you move down.

You are losing the protections that a good design can give you.

Comment: The problem is that the method (not mine) that actually handle gui events treats everything on a single function call, where it gives you just what type of data was it, and the gui ID. This sucks, cause its very not OO..What Im trying to do is make an approach to make creating gui stuff more modular, by giving a central class separeted gui objects with behaviours.

Comment: More on the choices I made, what I was thinking on the IGui class is really create an interface for all gui elements that can exist, not really a base class. Its not all pure because a element will not use everything.